# Slanted Border nth Child Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've found a solution to having slanted borders on my navigation: http://jsfiddle.net/Hfkk7/1101/

And I've got six items in my list. I've got the hover and active states working well with active:after using pngs.

My issue now is selecting the element to the left or right of the active state on its siblings hover to remove the right or left background image.

So let's say the 4th element is active. When I hover over element 5 I need the border on the right of 4 to change even though it's already been set to have an active bg color or whatever.

Hover on 3 I need the left background on 4 to change etc. etc.

I'm trying to do something like this with hover in jQuery:

```
$(".third").hover(function(){
    $(".second.active:after").addClass("active-hover");
});
```

Trying to do everything with CSS only, but to no avail thus far.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the class from all elements *before* setting the new one:

`$('.active-hover').removeClass('active-hover');`

Comment: Not having any luck with that working correctly either.

Comment: Can you include the relevant javascript in your fiddle?

Comment: Not sure you have it working in jsfiddle. You need to tell jsfiddle to load the jquery lib, fix some other js errors

Comment: Here's the actual example I have up that I'm testing on my site: http://justinlbannisterllc.com/nav-test/                                         It's a bit easier to see what I'm trying to do on there with the active element. So if you're the fourth list item, so the active state, I need the hover on the left element to change the right background and vice versa on the right element next to it I need the left background to change.

Comment: When you detect a click on a nav link, you should: remove all existing "active" classes from other nav links. The code I provides does this, though you may need to tweak the class name. Then, add the "active" class to the current link.